# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. Can't copy Nested Images to different location with same directory structure

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, permission-denied

I need to extract from dataset images with specific annotation. While doing it I faced up with **Permission denied Error**.The json files copies successfully, but image files not. Hoping for your advices.

The "js_files" and "img_files" variables arfe list contaning the location of each file

```
def comparizon(js_files,img_files):
    js = js_files
    imgs = img_files
    dst = "datasets/preprocessed/차량 외관 영상 데이터/Data/Training/원천데이터/"



    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dst))

    for i in range(len(js_files)):
        with open(js[i], 'r', encoding='UTF8') as json_file:
            contents = json.loads(json_file.read())
            objects = contents["learningDataInfo"]["objects"]
            for obj in objects:
                if "P00" in obj["classId"]:
                    print("Copying this file to new folder")


                    #creating destination of img file                    
                    components_img = imgs[i].split(os.path.sep)
                    img_dst = f'{dst}{components_img[6]}/{components_img[7]}/'
                    img_filename = components_img[-1]
                    
                    #creating destination of js file                    
                    components_js = js[i].split(os.path.sep)
                    js_dst = f'{dst}{components_js[6]}/{components_js[7]}/'
                    js_name = components_js[-1]
                    
                    # copy js file to new location
                    if not os.path.exists(js_dst):
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(js_dst),exist_ok=True)

                    shutil.copy2(js[i], js_dst)

                    # copy img file to new location
                    if not os.path.exists(img_dst):
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(img_dst),exist_ok=True)

                    shutil.copy2(imgs[i], dst)
                    print("Sucsessfully copied")
```

```
Copying this file to new folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Haidar\Workspace1\Transport Object Detection\datasets\filtering.py", line 73, in <module>
    comparizon(tr_json_files,tr_img_files)
  File "d:\Haidar\Workspace1\Transport Object Detection\datasets\filtering.py", line 63, in comparizon
    shutil.copy2(imgs[i], img_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Haidari Iskandarzoda\anaconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 436, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Haidari Iskandarzoda\anaconda3\Lib\shutil.py", line 258, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'datasets/preprocessed/차량 외관 영상 데이터/Data/Training/원천데이터/006_A4/2017_검정_트림A/C_211222_AU_006_17_BK_A_T_02_001.jpg'
```